# How to find if an object is from a class but not superclass?

Tags: c#, class, object

In C# how can you find if an object is an instance of certain class but not any of that class’s superclasses?

“is” will return true even if the object is actually from a superclass.

Comment: Ali, you meant to ask about subclasses, not superclasses. If D descends from B, then D is a subclass and B is D's superclass.

Comment: @RobKennedy Which makes no sense what so ever if you see to the semantic meaning of sub/super as in subset/superset. I guess it's our little internal joke as programmers.

Comment: Actually, @Alex, it makes *perfect* sense. A type is simply the set of all values that have that type. Any value of type `D` is thus a member of the set **D** as well as of the set **B**, but there are members of the set **B** that are not members of **D**. The type **D** is therefore a subset of **B**. We express that with the notation `D <: B`. Check out [*Types and Programming Languages* by Benjamin C. Pierce](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~bcpierce/tapl/index.html).

Comment: I guess if I would see at the natural world, **Tigers** would be a subset of the group **Cats**, and **Cats** would be a subset of **Animals**. Which is what you are describing. But if we were to implement these in code, **Cat** would have properties and methods that **Animal** does not have, and **Tiger** would have properties and methods that **Cat** does not have. Thus the relationship is inverted, right?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
typeof(SpecifiedClass) == obj.GetType()
```

Comment: -1 This does not answer the question - it is not possible for one type to inherit from another without also inheriting from all other types in the inheritance chain.

Comment: This answer works, and funny enough, it works for all question versions (check history) - both for "superclass" and "subclass".

Answer (score 3):

You could compare the type of your object to the Type of the class that you are looking for:

```
class A { }
class B : A { }

A a = new A();
if(a.GetType() == typeof(A)) // returns true
{
}

A b = new B();
if(b.GetType() == typeof(A)) // returns false
{
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately this is not possible in C# as C# does not support multiple inheritance.  Give this inheritance tree:

```
GrandParent
  Parent
   Child
```

The `Child` will always be an instance of every type above it in the inheritance chain.

Comment: After looking at your answer for a few minutes, I think I know what you mean. I think.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at a couple of methods on the Type class:
Type.IsInstaceOf
and
Type.IsSubclassOf

You can pass in the class you're looking for and get the information you need.

Comment: That is when you want to compare two objects with each other. My case is to compare an object with a class.

Comment: It's true these are types, but you can get the Type class for an object with obj.GetType.

Example:
obj.GetType().IsSubclassOf(typeof(ClassYouAreLookingFor))
or
obj.GetType().IsInstanceOf(typeof(ClassYouAreLookingFor))

Should accomplish what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
if(Obj.GetType() == typeof(ClassName))
```

This worked for me